# DECS data not displaying in view on first import

Tags: rdbms, lotus-domino

I've created DECS/DCR configuration for my database and it's able to create, read, update, delete which means connectivity wise it is OK.

However, on first import of the data from Oracle 10g database, only the key field appear on the view that I created to display the data. The rest of the columns/fields are all empty. I've checked the properties of each documents and the fields and their values are inside the documents. They will only appear in the view after I edit and save each of them.

I've checked the 'Store data locally' property of the other fields in their form and also make sure the database property "Allow connections to external databases using DCRs" is checked each time after I do the testing.

What did I miss?

Comment: When you check the properties, do the fields have the correct type and do they have the summary flag set?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Yes, the fields are of correct type. And yes the fields all have SUMMARY Field Flags. Why is that? I thought that's normal. And the key fields actually has 2. One is the normal "keyname" with SUMMARY, and the other is "$RTACT__keyname" without SUMMARY.

Comment: Yes, Summary is what you want.  Non-Summary would be invisible to views and editing the docs would change them to summary, making them visible.  (That's assuming that the fields exist on the form that you're using, which causes the editor to change them to Summary.) So I was thinking that if DECs was creating Non-Summary that would explain what you are seiing.  Did you check the fields before you had edited the document, or after?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Yes I checked the fields before and after the editing and on both occasion the fields have SUMMARY in them. The fields are created in the form, else DECS don't know what to mapped to. The first import that I meant is the 'Initialize Keys' button in the Virtual Fields Activity form in the DECS Administrator. The Non-Summary that the DECS created is only for the key field. Could this have to do with ACL, Author etc? Because, after the first import, all the documents' Modified By is the server, although I'm the one clicking the button.

Comment: Hmmm... I had DECS and LEI crossed up in my mind. I'm afraid I don't know enough about DECS, DECS Administrator, etc. to be of further help here.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz Found my answer. Thanks for the SUMMARY thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found the culprit. Apparently I need to choose the second or third option for the Data Storage. Even though I've checked the 'Store Data Locally' property of the fields, that is valid for DCR only, not DECS.

When I said the fields and their values are in the document property, actually those info are lively pulled from the Oracle WHILE THE VIRTUAL FIELDS ACTIVITY IS ACTIVE. If I stop the Virtual Field Activity, then none of the documents' document's property contains those fields and values. My mistake for thinking those are Notes data because they seem so real (with correct field names, SUMMARY and all).

But still it beats the purpose of DECS if you need to have the data in Notes in order to have them displayed in the view.

To @RichardSchwartz, thanks for at least providing some directions regarding the SUMMARY thing. Never knew about that.

[image: skrinshotte]